# Restrict SELECT operation to users within the same organisation

Tags: sql, postgresql, dart, supabase, row-level-security

I've created an application where users must register using an organisation key (a uuid that is created when a new organisation is added to the `organisations` table). The registration of a new user triggers a member instance to be created in the `members` table, where the `organisation_id` is automatically populated from the new `auth.users` instance's metadata and references the `organisation` table.

My table definitions are as follows:

The organisations table:

```
create table
  public.organisations (
    id uuid not null default uuid_generate_v4 (),
    created_at timestamp without time zone not null default now(),
    company_email character varying(150) not null,
    company_name character varying(150) not null,
    administrator_email character varying(150) not null,
    administrator_first_name character varying(150) not null,
    administrator_last_name character varying(150) not null,
    total_seats integer not null,
    available_seats integer not null,
    constraint organisations_duplicate_pkey primary key (id)
  ) tablespace pg_default;
```

The members table:

```
create table
  public.members (
    id uuid not null,
    organisation_id uuid not null,
    email character varying not null,
    last_name character varying not null,
    first_name character varying not null,
    job_title character varying null,
    employee_number character varying null,
    dark_theme boolean not null default false,
    user_color character varying(11) not null default generate_random_pastel_color (),
    constraint members_pkey primary key (id),
    constraint members_id_fkey foreign key (id) references auth.users (id) on delete cascade,
    constraint members_organisation_id_fkey foreign key (organisation_id) references organisations (id) on delete cascade
  ) tablespace pg_default;
```

Its important that members may only be able to view information of other members if they share the same organisation_id, so I would like to create a row level security policy that restricts access like this, but I am hitting a road block - whenever I attempt to read my data client side, I get NULL returned.

I know that the issue is with my policy, because everything works as intended when I ommit it and filter the organisation members client side, like so:

```
static Future<List<MemberModel>> getMemberModelsOfUserOrganisation({required SupabaseClient supabaseClient, required MembersSupabaseTable membersSupabaseTable}) async {

    MemberModel currentMemberModel = await getUserMemberModel(supabaseClient: supabaseClient, membersSupabaseTable: membersSupabaseTable);
    String currentMemberOrganisationID = currentMemberModel.organisationID;

    final List<dynamic> response = await supabaseClient
        .from(membersSupabaseTable.tableName)
        .select()
        .eq(membersSupabaseTable.organisationID, currentMemberOrganisationID);

    return response.map((map) => MemberModel.fromMap(map)).toList();
  }
```

My (non-functional) policy is defined as follows:

```
CREATE POLICY members_organization_policy
    ON public.members
    USING (organisation_id = (SELECT organisation_id FROM public.members WHERE id = auth.uid()))
```

It is my understanding that this filter would be unnecessary if I properly restricted access to the members table (I might be wrong, please correct me if I'm misunderstanding).

How would I define a RLS policy that only allows members to SELECT other members if and only if they share an organisation_id with the current user?

Comment: What do you get if you run `SELECT organisation_id FROM public.members WHERE id = auth.uid()`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe If I replace `auth.uid()` with the id of a particular member, I get the organisation_id of said member, which is what I would expect - am I on the wrong track? My idea was to compare the organisation_id of the members with the organisation_id of the current user.

Comment: If the comparison is `true`, the policy would pass. If false it would not. At least, that's the idea.

Comment: The idea sounds right, so I am wondering if there is a problem in the implementation. For example, `auth.iud()` might not return what you expect in the context of your application. That's why I suggested running the subquery from your application.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Do you know if there is another method that can be used to extract the current user's `auth.users.id` field? This is quite confusing seeing as though the function definition is what I expect: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/row-level-security

Comment: I am just blindly guessing. If you have the policy in place, and the function returns what you think it should, does it work if you run SQL statements against the database manually? The idea is to narrow down where the problem might be.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe It does, yes. I've also verified that the policy doesn't restrict SELECT operations for the current user's member data as well. I know for a fact that no data is being passed to the client, so the policy is not returning `true` when `auth.uid()` is used. I think this a symptom of a different issue - I'll broaden my search. Thanks for chatting this through with me. I appreciate your time. Will update with an answer when I get it right.